# Assigning mulitple variables to a random item in list. Python

Tags: python, variables

I want to have multiple variables that are set to random elements in the list. Right now I'm doing it somewhat like this:

```
from random import choice

list = ["a", "b"]
foo = choice(list)
bar = choice(list)
baz = choice(list) #etc.
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. I tried

```
 foo = bar = baz = choice(list)
```

but, of course it just sets them all to a single element of the list choosen once by random, and I want each variable to be set to new random.choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Alex suggested but without getting list as result:

```
foo, bar, baz = [random.choice(list) for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) if you want to pluck out three *distinct* elements from the list (i.e. `foo` is never equal to `bar`, which might not be what you want):

```
foo, bar, baz = random.sample(l, 3)
```

I renamed your variable to `l` because `list` is a built-in type. Overriding it by accident won't be pretty.

Comment: The problem with `sample` is that it works "without replacement", i.e. won't work in case when you need more samples than there are elements in the original list. See http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample Of course it might work in this particular case (depends on the dataset and the needs), but it's worth noting.

Comment: sample() returns ValueError: "sample larger than population" in my case, since I have more variables than elements in the list.

Comment: [Alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12420622/464744) is the correct one. I misread the question...

Answer (score 5):

maybe create a list with choice outputs? Something like

```
choices = [choice(list) for i in range(10)]
```

in which you have 10 elements? Also I would rename `list` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider putting them in a `dict` then using `somedict['foo']` style access:

```
from random import choice

CHOICES = ('a', 'b')
choices = {name: choice(CHOICES) for name in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}
```